# Aurelia is messing with injected iframes

Tags: javascript, iframe, aurelia

The following js error is forms the crux of my issue.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'postMessage' of null
at n.saveField (thirdPartyStuff.js?v=Dev:formatted:297)
at n.handleEvent (thirdPartyStuff.js?v=Dev:formatted:305)
at r (thirdPartyStuff.js?v=Dev:formatted:343)
```

Based on this link I believe aurelia is to blame.

```
https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js/issues/171
```

Here is the view i'm using.

```
<template>
    <require from="cms-content-control"></require>

    <div show.bind="!model.partialCardDetails">
        <content-control 
            name-is-valid.bind="nameIsValid"
            card-is-valid.bind="cardIsValid"
            expiry-is-valid.bind="expiryIsValid"
            cvn-is-valid.bind="cvnIsValid"
            secure-field-callback.bind="secureFieldCallback()"
        ></content-control>
    </div>
</template>
```

This is the control object.

```
import { bindable, noView, inject } from "aurelia-framework";
import "../thirdPartyStuff.js";

@noView
@inject(Element)
export class ContentControl {

    @bindable nameIsValid: boolean;
    @bindable cardIsValid: boolean;
    @bindable expiryIsValid: boolean;
    @bindable cvnIsValid: boolean;
    @bindable secureFieldCallback: (fieldIsValidCheck: (isValid: boolean) => { }) => () => {};

    constructor(private readonly element: Element) {
        let div = document.createElement("div");
        div.id = "secure-field-name";
        element.appendChild(div);
        div = document.createElement("div");
        div.id = "secure-field-card";
        element.appendChild(div);
        div = document.createElement("div");
        div.id = "secure-field-expiry";
        element.appendChild(div);
        div = document.createElement("div");
        div.id = "secure-field-cvn";
        element.appendChild(div);
    }

    attached() {
        this.thirdPartyStuff();
    }

    thirdPartyStuff() {
        // A third part script called that injects iframes into the divs injected.
    }

    detached() {
        while (this.element.firstChild)
            this.element.removeChild(this.element.firstChild);
    }
}
```

And the whole site is sitting at the div level

```
<body>
    <div aurelia-app="/app/main"></div>
</body>
```

My issue is that if a load the view and then navigate away and back I get the post error details at the top. From what i've read its probably due to the fact aurelia is messing with the iframe content but im not sure.

Is there a way to tell aurelia to completely ignore a component and do no binding changes?

**EDIT 1**

Some more info as requested as to what happens in third party script.

This is where postMessage is used.

```
secureField.prototype.saveField = function () {
    if (this.needsSave == true) {
        this.iframe.contentWindow.postMessage("save", "*");
        this.needsSave = false;
    }
};
```

This is how the iframe is created

```
secureField.prototype.createIFrame = function () {
    this.iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
    this.iframe.id = this.id;
    this.iframe.setAttribute("allowTransparency", "true");
    this.iframe.style.cssText = 'z-index: 9999; display: block; border: 0px none transparent; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent; width: 100%; height: 100%; background: transparent;';
    this.div.appendChild(this.iframe);
    // now set the iFrme's URL
    this.iframe.src = this.sharedUrl();
    return this.iframe;
};
```

Event handler that calls saveField

```
secureField.prototype.handleEvent = function (event) {
    var ev = new fieldEvent(event);
    // call callback if a save for this field
    if (ev.targetField == this.fieldType && this.callbackFunc && !ev.valueHasFocus) {
        this.needsSave = !(ev.valueIsSaved);
        this.callbackFunc(ev);
    }
    // if a focus in and not for this field, force a save
    if (ev.valueHasFocus && ev.targetField != this.fieldType) {
        this.saveField();
    }
    // flag dirty if this field received focus
    if (ev.valueHasFocus && ev.targetField == this.fieldType) {
        this.needsSave = true;
    }
};
```

Comment: we need more information to help you. Where is the postMessage property? Show us the `thirdPartyStuff()`content

Comment: @FabioLuz I have added more information about postMessage.